# Cakephp 3.x how do i extend the cake schema class?

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to add a few additional options to the schema $_fieldDefaults array for some documenting purposes.
I tried copying the class and including it in the model in place of the cake schema class but somewhere down the line  the constructor is looking for an instance of the cake schema class and not accepting my class.

Does anyone know if it is possable to simply swap out the schema class or would I need to start from the ground up and create a while new db driver to achieve my goals?

If i need to create a driver does anyone have an example or list of requirements needed to do so?

As a side thought,
I am also tossing around the idea of declaring a new public var in the table which holds the schema fields  and its options and then just looping through it in the build schema function so that I can always refer to the new variable instead of the schema object however that sounds wrong-ish but simpler than re inventing the wheel.

Comment: It would help if you'd show an example of what exactly (code wise)  you're trying to add to the schema, and why exactly (what does "_documenting purposes_" mean?) you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to extend the original class in your new class.

```
<?php
namespace \your\new\class\namespace

use original\schema\class\schemaClassName

class YourNewClass extends schemaClassName {

//new code here

}
```